# AngularJS - Breeze - EF EntityQuery Issues

Tags: angularjs, entity-framework-6, breeze

I will preface this by saying I am new to the whole Angular / Breeze world.  I have watched John Papa's videos on Pluralsight so I have some idea of how everything is supposed to work.  I am using the HotTowel Angular Breeze SPA template by John Papa.  Even after watching his videos and doing some additional research I have been banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why I cannot get any data back to my view from Breeze / EF.  I did a "reverse engineer code first" of an existing database to get code first files.  I am able to get metadata back.  I can, in a browser, pull up the data for an entity I am trying to bind to my view so it appears that the web api portion is working fine.  I am not used to debugging Angular apps, but I do not see any errors in the developer tools window on Chrome.  I am sure this is something very simple, but I am not seeing it.  Any help would be awesome.  Code is below.  If I need to post more let me know.

Thank you,

RG

DataContext.js

```
(function () {
'use strict';

var serviceId = 'datacontext';
angular.module('app').factory(serviceId, ['common', 'entityManagerFactory', 'model', datacontext]);

function datacontext(common, entityManagerFactory, model) {
    var $q = common.$q;
    var Predicate = breeze.Predicate;
    var EntityQuery = breeze.EntityQuery;
    var entityNames = model.entityNames;
    var getLogFn = common.logger.getLogFn;
    var log = getLogFn(serviceId);
    var logError = getLogFn(serviceId, 'error');
    var logSuccess = getLogFn(serviceId, 'success');
    var manager = entityManagerFactory.newManager();
    var brand = [];

    var service = {
        getBrands: getBrands
    };

    return service;

    function getBrands() {
        var orderBy = 'BrandID';
        return EntityQuery.from(entityNames.brand)
            .orderBy(orderBy)
            .using(manager).execute()
            .then(querySucceeded)
            .fail(_queryFailed);

        function querySucceeded(data) {
            brand = data.results[0];
            logSuccess('Retrieved [Brands] from remote data source', brand.length, true);
            return brand;
        }
    }

    function _queryFailed(error) {
        var msg = config.appErrorPrefix + 'Error retrieving data.' + error.message;
        logError(msg, error);
        throw error;
    }
}})();
```

Controller

```
(function () {
'use strict';
var controllerId = 'empLifeCycleHome';
angular.module('app').controller(controllerId, ['common', 'config', 'datacontext', empLifeCycleHome]);

function empLifeCycleHome(common, config, datacontext) {
    var getLogFn = common.logger.getLogFn;
    var log = getLogFn(controllerId);

    var vm = this;
    vm.title = 'Employee Life Cycle Home';
    vm.brand = [];

    activate();

    function activate() {
        common.activateController(getBrands(), controllerId)
            .then(function () { log('Activated Employee Life Cycle Home View'); });
    }

    function getBrands() {
        return datacontext.getBrands().then(function (data) {
            return vm.brand = data;
        });
    }
}})();
```

View - (I am using Controller As syntax.  Controller is "vm".)

```
<section id="empLifeCycleHome" class="mainbar">
<section class="matter">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="widget wviolet">
                <div data-cc-widget-header title="{{vm.title}}"></div>
                <div>
                    <div data-ng-repeat="b in vm.brand">
                        <div>
                            <h5>{{b.brandName}}</h5>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="widget-foot">
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Data returned in browser when navigating to the Brand action...

```
[{"$id": "1",
"$type": "EmpSvcsDataModel.Brand, EmpSvcsDataModel",
"BrandID": 1,
"BrandName": "Maintenance USA",
"InsertDate": "2015-09-08T12:58:12.163",
"LastUpdateDate": null}]
```

Comment: When you run the app with your browser's developer tools open, do you see the query being sent and the data returned?  What is the value of `brand` in your `querySucceeded` function?

Comment: I am only seeing the metadata returned.  I don't see the query for the Brand data.

Comment: I now am getting the Brand data back, but it is not binding.

Comment: I figured it out.  I had some issues with my model classes, and with some naming of data being passed back from my datacontext js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had some issues with my model classes, and with some naming of data being passed back from my datacontext js file.